# Raspicam Web Streaming

Tags: video, camera, streaming

I am currently working on a Rasperry Pi robot and I've been able to control my robot through an html web page..I just started playing around with the Raspicam and I want to add a video stream to my webpage so that I could use my robot without having to physically be there. 
I've done a tutorial on using mjpeg-streamer and the results were really poor, by this I mean, I was only able to achieve around 3-4 fps. Obviously this lag is too slow to keep up with a fast moving robot!
Does anyone know a better way to stream this video with better performance?

NB: My knowledge on HTML and Linux all together are very limited since this is really my first project on a linux-based system as well as my first experience with web serving! So please, if you can, try to be detailed about your answers so that it is easy for me to understand and learn.

Answer (score 2):

I used the uv4l driver + streaming option, I only required one connection for streaming through a website.

[This tutorial worked for me](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14)

`uv4l --driver raspicam --auto-video_nr --width 640 --height 480`, seems to work smoother/faster than the default in the tutorial :)